# Pl/sql: Re-arrange strings in a record

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a record in a column which is as follows,

`4050 Belmont Ave, Unit-6` this record has to be updated in the following format :

`Unit-6, 4050 Belmont Ave`.

What functionality can be used to rearrange the strings within a record?

Thanks
Franklin

Comment: well you need to have some rule you can apply, then maybe use regular expressions.

Answer (score 3):

You could use simple string functions to look for the first comma and swap the substrings before and after:

```sql
SELECT value,
       CASE INSTR(value, ', ')
       WHEN 0
       THEN value
       ELSE SUBSTR(value, INSTR(value, ', ') + 2)
            || ', '
            || SUBSTR(value, 1, INSTR(value, ', ') - 1)
       END AS switched_value
FROM   table_name;
```

Or, you could use regular expressions (which are shorter to write but slower to execute):

```sql
SELECT value,
       REGEXP_REPLACE( value, '^(.*?), (.*)$', '\2, \1') AS switched_value
FROM   table_name;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (value) AS
SELECT '4050 Belmont Ave, Unit-6' FROM DUAL;
```

Both output:

> | VALUE | SWITCHED_VALUE |
> | --- | --- |
> | 4050 Belmont Ave, Unit-6 | Unit-6, 4050 Belmont Ave |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=42421331d7b3a91fe604b6492d15e351)*